# Create FileStream in memory instead of saving a physical file on disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am uploading a file to an api, and I have to copy my requestStream to a FileStream in order to post the file to the API. My code below works, but I have to save the file to a temp folder to create the FileStream, and then I have to clean up the temp folder again after the operation. Is there a cleaner way of doing that - e.g. creating the FileStream in memory (if that's possible) instead of saving it to the disk?

```
Stream requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

     //Create filestream by making a temporary physical file
     using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\tempFolder\" fileName))                                     
     {
         await requestStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
         var postedFile = ms.CreateMedia(fileName, folder.Id, "file");                                    
         postedFile.SetValue("umbracoFile", fileName, fileStream);                                      
         ms.Save(postedFile);
     }

     // Clean up
     if ((System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\tempFolder\" + fileName)))
     {
         System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\tempFolder\" + fileName);
     }
```

Comment: You are looking for [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream).

Comment: Frederico, I have been puzzling with the MemoryStream approach, I couldn't make it work, so I ended up doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the `requestStream` directly? It is an instance of `Stream` and your API end point expects an instance of `Stream`, there is no need to copy the content of `requestStream` to any intermediary point unless you want to add unnecessary overhead.

```
Stream requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

var postedFile = ms.CreateMedia(fileName, folder.Id, "file");
postedFile.SetValue("umbracoFile", fileName, requestStream);
ms.Save(postedFile);
```

Comment: Wow, that was easier than the detour I was making ... Thanks, it works! Can I extract the filename from the requestStream if I don't know it?

Comment: @micknt - not from the `requestStream` instance but you might be able to get it from the header in the `Request` or `Request.Content`. You would have to inspect it at debug time or see how the caller is sending over the file name if it is included.

Comment: Thank you @Igor, I will try looking into the request for that information.

Answer (score 0):

.Net doesn't really provide a good in-memory solution. It is good to create your own to save resources and encapsulate more functionality.

Check out this guide [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-and-save-multipartform-data-in-webapi-2/)